# How to fetch respective columns from BigQuery table with values matching from another table column joined?

Tags: sql, join, google-bigquery, case

**SCENARIO:**
Have got two BigQuery Tables A and B, with multiple columns and common key column. Need to join both tables with common key column as well as fetch respective values from another table as mentioned in below sample.

**INPUT:**
Have got two tables

**Table A:**

```
store   category    city
11      aaa         xx
12      bbb         yy
12      ccc         zz
13      ddd         xy
```

**Table B:**

```
store   sale1   sale2   sale3
11      0.5     0.75    0.25
12      1.2     1.25    1.23
13      0.9     0.87    0.54
```

**EXPECTED OUTPUT - Result Table C:**

```
store   category    city    sale
11      aaa         xx      0.5
12      bbb         yy      1.25
12      ccc         zz      1.23
13      ddd         xy      0.87
```

**OUTPUT EXPLAINED:**

**Point 1:** Join two tables with common column 'store'

**Point 2:** Check if column category == 'aaa', then fetch column 'sale1' from Table B and if category in ('bbb','ddd'), then fetch column 'sale2' and if category == 'ccc', then fetch column 'sale3' and store respective value in Result Table C as column 'sale'.

**TRIED BIGQUERY:**

```
with res as 
    (select 
    a.store,
    a.category,
    a.city
    )
SELECT store, category, city,   
    case
        when category in ('aaa') then sale=b.sale1
        when category in ('bbb','ddd') then sale=b.sale2
        when category in ('ccc') then sale=b.sale3
    end
    as sale
FROM `tableA` AS a
JOIN `tableB` AS b
ON a.store = CAST(b.store AS STRING)
```

Need help. Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `case` expression:

```
select a.store, a.category,
       (case when a.category = 'aaa' then b.sale1
             when a.category in ('bbb', 'ddd') then b.sale2
             when a.category in ('ccc') then b.sale3
        end) as sale
from `tableA` a join
     `tableB` b
     on a.store = cast(b.store as string) ;
```

Actually, your query is basically correct (although the CTE is superfluous) except for the `case` expression.  the `sale=` is not appropriate.  A `case` expression returns a value.  It can then be assigned to a column using `as`.

Answer (score 0):

Below is for BiQquery Standard SQL

Below solution can look like over-engineering, but it can be your preference in cases when you want to keep your mapping rules separately from code and / or numbers of such rules will make code unmanageable, etc.

```
#standardSQL
WITH map AS (
  SELECT 'sale1' column, ['aaa'] categories UNION ALL
  SELECT 'sale2', ['bbb', 'ddd'] UNION ALL
  SELECT 'sale3', ['ccc']
)
SELECT a.*, SPLIT(kv, ':')[SAFE_OFFSET(1)] sale
FROM `project.dataset.tableA` a
JOIN `project.dataset.tableB` b
  ON a.store = CAST(b.store AS STRING)
JOIN map m
  ON a.category IN UNNEST(m.categories)
JOIN UNNEST(SPLIT(TRIM(TO_JSON_STRING(b), '{}'))) kv
  ON TRIM(SPLIT(kv, ':')[SAFE_OFFSET(0)], '"') = m.column
```

If to apply above code to sample data from your question - output is

```
Row store   category    city    sale     
1   11      aaa         xx      0.5  
2   12      bbb         yy      1.25     
3   12      ccc         zz      1.23     
4   13      ddd         xy      0.87
```